# How can I remove unnecessary columns in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

How do I remove the specific column, from a `DataGridView` control, that is indicated in the picture?

[image]

Comment: In the future, might I humbly suggest indicating the area in your screenshots using a *contrasting* color. Red is very popular. :-)  But thanks for including one! Makes the question much easier to answer.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I was searching where is the mark in picture. Off-course Red is popular to mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That particular column is called a **Row Header**. Its purpose is to allow the user to select the entire row with a single click, and to indicate which row is currently selected.

You can hide it by setting the [`RowHeadersVisible` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheadersvisible.aspx) of the `DataGridView` control to False.

Comment: @FullmetalBoy: This is the Exact and simple solution for your Problem just to set one property of DataGridView as False that's it
@Cody: Great Answer